# Will my old acer aspire one netbook be compatible with the latest version of ubuntu

Tags: acer

I have an old acer aspire one netbook running ubuntu 14.04. I have tried downloading all of the updates with little success. After downloading a small percentage the machine tells me "unable to download all updates". Not sure what to do now. I've recently become interested in the Linux operating system. I still use Windows 10 at the office, Mac at home on my main desktop and MBP. Looking for something different.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL or *end-of-life* thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: We have no details on what your old netbook is, nor the architecture (is it x86/i686? or x86_64/amd64? or something else?)  You can download and try ubuntu before you install (
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install), and I used an 2007 asus eeepc (intel atom n270) to test Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (and other *flavors*) which was released earlier this month, but a more modern netbook would handle more and thus provide more choices.  The intel n270 however won't run later than Lubuntu 19.04 for example (19.04 being EOL)

Comment: @xiota, BEWARE when posting links, you didn't use a Lubuntu/Ubuntu/Canonical web site, check with https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours for official web sites for flavors. Also please note Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has 5 years of free/standard support, which yes can be moved to extended support, but are off-topic here and may require payment.  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS reaches EOL in 2021-April (being a *flavor* it has 3 years only of support) with extended support for desktops only available on *amd64*, 5 years only on amd64 GNOME desktop, ESM is available for i386 though on servers, and main Ubuntu on amd64.